# CSV Content in lowercase before processing?

Tags: python, csv, lowercase

Hey everyone :) I'm struggling because I have a big CSV-File where in one column the data should be considered case-insensitive, how can I fix that Python considers all rows of that column as lower (anton = ANTon)? That's what I tried:

```
def CSV_firstnameshouldbelowered(csv_data):
    csv_record[First_Name] = csv_record[First_Name].lower()

    firstnameislowernow = {
    First_Name: csv_record[First_Name],
    Age: csv_record[Age]
}

return firstnameislowernow
```

Sadly I can't use .lower() here because it's not a string. How can I change that columns content into lowercase? The part "firstnameislowernow" should be modified with the implementation before, otherwise I can't further process the data with my code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert to string first, then use `lower()`

```
firstNameStr = str(csv_record[First_Name]) 
firstNameStr = firstNameStr.lower()
```